# Mathematica: Manipulate ContourPlot3D with many functions error

Tags: function, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to Manipulate three functions and choose with popup menu which of them it will show. I haven't placed the variables yet (they would be in the place of 16, 25, 2 etc).

For some reason, when i run it, it gives back the Manipulate box with the popup menu but instead of showing the ContourPlot3D, it shows its code. Can you find the error, please?

```
Clear[x, y, z, ell, mu, du]

ell[x_, y_, z_] := x^2/16 + y^2/25 + z^2/2
mu[x_, y_, z_] := x^2/1 + y^2/2 - z^2/1
du[x_, y_, z_] := x^2/2 - y^2/4 - z^2/1

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[
  F == 1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -3, 3}], {F, {ell, mu, du}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

And this is the example from mathematica documentation:

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {f, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

Answer (score 0):

one way:

```
 f["ell"][x_, y_, z_] := x^2/16 + y^2/25 + z^2/2
 f["mu"][x_, y_, z_] := x^2/1 + y^2/2 - z^2/1
 f["du"][x_, y_, z_] := x^2/2 - y^2/4 - z^2/1
 Manipulate[
     ContourPlot3D[
          f[key][x, y, z] == 1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -3, 3}],
                {{key,"ell"}, {"ell", "mu", "du"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]